# What is the best search engine for mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I was using

```
SELECT * LIKE search WHERE ...
```

on small table and it always work great ! but now I am playing with massive database and having huge performance issue.

I add full text search on my table column and I run this query :

```
    $run = mysql_query("SELECT title
              FROM table 
              WHERE MATCH ( title ) 
              AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) ORDER BY $ok DESC LIMIT 
              $s, $p");
```

(variable $ok is index and very fast when browse)

But it take 12-15 seconds to load (around 6M row on MyIsam table) is it normal ?

Explain Query:

id : 1
select_type : SIMPLE
table : testv1
type : fulltext
possible_keys  : title
key : title
key_len  : 0 
rows : 1
extra : using where

I am using debian dedicated fast server (6 core 8GB ram)

I know about sphinx and lucene but I want to know if there is a way to make a fast 0.5 sec load search query on a 6M row whitout using those engine.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the table structure? What's `explain` result for this query?

Comment: Suggestion: mysql has been depreciated. Use Mysqli (improved) or Procedural method.

Comment: May get a quicker answer in database stackexchange https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions best of luck.

Comment: MySQL cannot use the fulltext search and the index on `$ok` at the same time. Your `explain` output should contain `using filesort` for that reason (not sure why it doesn't). The speed will depend heavily on your search term. If you are looking for a single word that only appears in a handful of rows, it will be fast. If the fulltext search itself will find a lot of rows that have to be sorted (or if you e.g. combine several frequent terms by `+`), it will be a lot slower. In some cases you might be able to optimize it a bit, but a specialized search engine should be an option at some point.